# How to change foreground + bordercolor when a button is disabled windows 8?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a button in a stack panel

```
<StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="CreateBtn" Content="Create" Style="{StaticResource PopUpButton}"  Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 60 30 0" Command="{Binding SaveCardTypeCommand}" />

</StackPanel>
```

that's use a style in a file

```
<Style x:Key="PopUpButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#1172b7"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1172b7"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
</Style>
```

I need to change color to red of the content and the borderbrush when the button is disabled

How can I do this?

Best regards

Comment: Are you disabling button from back end code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using expression blend edit the default template of the button and customize the visual states. You can define animations to every visual state.

```
 <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

[image]

Comment: Add visual state groups to the root element of your control template. You can add several visual states to it. Expression blend helps you to add or edit states easily. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/09/20/retemplating-in-blend.aspx